An ordinary Sunday night riddle
Three graves open with no tears
And in crouch three soldiers
Not in a row but paired and solo
Where they go, they go low
They brace, they flex
They do their duty and relax

Three graves open with no tears, And in crouch three soldiers

 Are you bowling, the three soldiers being your two fingers and the thumb, fitting in the three holes.

Not in a row but paired and solo, Where they go, they go low

 

 The balls run low on the lane surface.

They brace, they flex, They do their duty and relax

 They spin down the lane aiming to strike the pins before ending in the pit.


A good way to spend a Sunday night...

Solved! Hope you enjoyed it!

I think this is referring to

 Inserting a three-pin plug into a plug socket.


Three graves open with no tears
And in crouch three soldiers

 The three graves here refer to the socket holes and the soldiers are the pins. The process of "opening" could be facilitated by the switch in the image above.

Not in a row but paired and solo

 Two on the bottom, horizontal. One on the top, vertical.

Where they go, they go low

 Usually plug sockets are positioned low on a wall (unless in a kitchen, for example).

They brace, they flex

 Unsure about brace, but "flex" refers to the insulated cables within the plug.

They do their duty and relax

 Facilitate the movement of electric current and stay still.


Related? :-)

@Randal'Thor Certainly related, if correct. Sorry, had not seen your question before +1

Excellent guess!  However it doesn't quite fit, as you point out rot13(cyht fbpxrgf ner fgngvbanel ba gur jnyy naq znlor uvtu, zrqvhz be ybj; gur evqqyr fcrpvsvrf gung gurfr 'tb' ybj')
